# Ошибка java: not a statement в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Вроде все написано корректно, но IntelliJ IDEA почему то выдает ошибку:

> java: not a statement

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 20;
        int b = 35;

        if (a == b) {
            System.out.println("a == b");
        } else if (a > b) {
            System.out.println("a > b");
        } else (a < b) {
                System.out.println("a < b");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Замените второй `else` на `else if`

Comment: @Saturn1401, а зачем его "менять", проверка на третье условие лишняя, и следует оставить просто `else`

Answer (score 3):

У `else` нельзя писать какие-то дополнительные условия в скобках. На то он и просто `else` (перевеодится как **иначе**, то есть читай как *если ни то и ни сё не подошло, то иначе...*). Если нужно соблюсти условие, то надо писать else **if**, как и в случае выше.

Кстати, `if`, так и переводится: **ЕСЛИ**, что интуитивно понятно, что хочется туда подставить *если ЧТО-ТО*, то есть хочется подставать какое-то условие. Что явно не хочется делать просто с else.

---

В целом, в конце можно оставить и просто `else`, тогда условие `(a < b)` надо просто удалить. Логически оно как раз будет всё правильно отрабатывать, ведь если а и b не равны и a не больше b, то значит a меньше b.

Answer (score 2):

Все верно, `else (a < b)` - это некорректно по синтаксису и будет выдавать ошибку компиляции.

Когда идёт цепочка `if-else-if`, то надо делать отступы в коде, чтобы было видно к какому блоку относится то или иное утверждение.

```
if (a == b) {
   System.out.println("a == b");
} else if (a > b) {
   System.out.println("a > b");
} else if (a < b) { // всегда верно, поэтому можно использовать просто else
   System.out.println("a < b");
}
```

В последнем операторе цепочки  оператор `if` можно опустить, т.к. в данном случае логически условие всегда верно. Если добавить ещё один блок `else`, то он никогда выполняться не будет и компилятор его удалит.

---

> ### [Оператор `if-then-else`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)
>
> Оператор `if-then-else` обеспечивает вторичный путь выполнения, когда предложение if принимает значение `false`.  Вы можете использовать оператор `if-then-else` в методе `applyBrakes()`, чтобы выполнить какое-либо действие, если тормоза задействуются, когда велосипед не движется.  В этом случае действие состоит в том, чтобы просто распечатать сообщение об ошибке о том, что велосипед уже остановился.
>
> ```
> void applyBrakes() {
>     if (isMoving) {
>         currentSpeed--;
>     } else {
>         System.err.println("Велосипед уже остановился!");
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Следующая программа, [IfElseDemo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/IfElseDemo.java), присваивает оценку на основе значения результата теста: A — за результат 90 % или выше, B — за результат 80 % или выше и т. д.
>
> ```
> class IfElseDemo {
>    public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>        int testscore = 76;
>        char grade;
>
>        if (testscore >= 90) >{
>            grade = 'A';
>        } else if (testscore >= 80) {
>            grade = 'B';
>        } else if (testscore >= 70) {
>            grade = 'C';
>        } else if (testscore >= 60) {
>            grade = 'D';
>        } else {
>            grade = 'F';
>        }
>        System.out.println("Grade = " + grade);
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> Результатом работы программы является:
>
> ```
> Grade = С
> ```
>
> Возможно, вы заметили, что значение grade может удовлетворять более чем одному выражению в составном операторе: 76 >= 70 и 76 >= 60. Однако, как только условие выполнено, соответствующие операторы выполняются (`grade = 'C';`) и остальные условия не оцениваются.

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.